# MutableLiveData share data with fragment gets me null

Tags: android, kotlin

**SharedViewModel**

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val feedback: MutableLiveData<Feedback> = MutableLiveData()

    fun setType(type: TYPE?) {
        this.feedback.value?.type = type
    }

    fun setPart(part: PART?) {
        this.feedback.value?.part = part
    }

    fun setStatus(status: STATUS?) {
        this.feedback.value?.status = status
    }

    fun setSoftware(software: SOFTWARE?) {
        this.feedback.value?.software = software
    }

    fun setHardware(hardware: HARDWARE?) {
        this.feedback.value?.hardware = hardware
    }


    fun getFeedback() : MutableLiveData<Feedback> = this.feedback
}
```

Setting value in **Fragment A**

```
val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

screen.setOnClickListener {
     model.setHardware(HARDWARE.SCREEN) // ENUM CLASS
}
```

Trying to print value in **Fragment B**

```
val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

print.setOnClickListener { println(model.getFeedback().value) } // NULL ;(
```

What I've tried so far:

- Replace code with an observer pattern in fragment B, still get null
- Tried to use navigator component shared data like this

```
val viewModel: SharedViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.checkout_graph)
```

Any help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is `LiveData` value will be `null` for the first time, so kotlin statement
`this.feedback.value?.hardware = hardware` wont execute after `value?.` please change the `value` so it will invoke changes to subscribers

```
fun setHardware(hardware: HARDWARE?) {
    this.feedback.value =  this.feedback.value?.apply{ this.hardware = hardware }?: Feedback(hardware = hardware) //if null set default
}
```

**Same applies for other methods in viewmodel**

Comment: When i use this solution I get a type mismatch : Type mismatch.
Required:
Feedback?
Found:
Unit?

Comment: Sorry I have updated the answer to use apply instead of let

Comment: Sorry to bother you again i got this now Error: Unresolved reference: it :/